# Is my proof that a closed set in the subspace topology is closed in the space topology correct?

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $A \subset Y$ is closed in $(Y, \mathcal{T_Y})$, and $Y$ is closed in $(X, \mathcal{T_X})$, then $A$ is closed in $(X, \mathcal{T_X})$

My proof is as follows:

$A$ closed wrt $\mathcal{T_Y}\implies A^c$ open, $Y$ closed $\implies Y^c \subset \mathcal{T_X}$

Since $A^c \subset Y^c$ by definition, $A^c$ must be open wrt $(X, \mathcal{T_X}) \implies A$ is closed wrt $(X, \mathcal{T_X})$

Comment: What’s $A^c$?  If $A\subset Y $ then the complement of $A$ *contains* the complement of $Y$

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, your proof is incorrect. Moreover, don't forget to indicate the topology with respect to which your subsets are open/closed subsets.

I suggest to argue in this way. If $A$ is a closed set in the subspace topology, then $Y\setminus A$ is an open set in the subspace topology, thus by definition $Y\setminus A = B\cap Y$, where $B$ is an open subset of $X$. Hence $A=Y\cap (X\setminus B)$, which is a closed subset of $X$ because it is the intersection of two closed subsets of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to the fact that the intersection of two closed subsets is closed.  That's all you really need to note.

So in all honesty I think your proof could be significantly more direct.

Comment: His proof isn’t just indirect; it’s incorrect. As @J.W.Tanner pointed out, if $A \subset Y$, then $A^c$ isn’t a subset of $Y^c$. Also, maybe this is just a typo, but $Y^c$ isn’t a subset of the topology on $X$, it’s an element of it.

Comment: @Joe:  I also noticed that it should have been $Y^c\color{red}\in\mathcal T_X$

Comment: I suspected that.  It kind of crossed me up and started to give me a headache.  I didn't read it very carefully.  Good catch. @Joe